# Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, selection-sort

So I am writing a selection sort algorithm that puts turns all the parts of the sort into methods. However, when I compile it, it returns the error:

Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
    public class Driver01
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        //input
         double[] myArray = {2.0, 3.7, 9.9, 8.1, 8.5, 7.4, 1.0, 6.2};

        //sort the array
         double[] sorted = process(myArray);

        //output
         System.out.print("" + sorted);



      }
      private static double findMax( int EndIndex, double[] enterArray) {
         double max = 0;
         int trueIndex = 0; 
         for( int x = 0; x < EndIndex; x++) {
               if(enterArray[x] > max) {
                  max = enterArray[x];
                  trueIndex = x;
               }
               }

      return trueIndex;
      }
      private static void swap(int swap1, int swap2, double[] enterArray) {
         double temp = 0;
         temp = enterArray[swap1];
         enterArray[swap1] = enterArray[swap2];
         enterArray[swap2] = enterArray[swap1];

      }
      private static double[] process(double[] enterArray) {
         int range = enterArray.length -1;
         for( int x = 0; x < enterArray.length-1; x++) {
            double j = findMax(range, enterArray);
            swap(j, range, enterArray);
            range = range -1;
         }
         return enterArray;
      }
      }
```

Revised Code:

```
import java.io.*;
    public class Driver01
   {
       public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        //input
         double[] myArray = {2.0, 3.7, 9.9, 8.1, 8.5, 7.4, 1.0, 6.2};

        //sort the array
         double[] sorted = process(myArray);

        //output
         System.out.print("" + sorted);



      }
      private static int findMax( int EndIndex, double[] enterArray) {
         double max = 0;
         int trueIndex = 0; 
         for( int x = 0; x < EndIndex; x++) {
               if(enterArray[x] > max) {
                  max = enterArray[x];
                  trueIndex = x;
               }
               }

      return trueIndex;
      }
      private static void swap(int swap1, int swap2, double[] enterArray) {
         double temp = 0;
         temp = enterArray[swap1];
         enterArray[swap1] = enterArray[swap2];
         enterArray[swap2] = enterArray[swap1];

      }
      private static double[] process(double[] enterArray) {
         int range = enterArray.length -1;
         for( int x = 0; x < enterArray.length-1; x++) {
            int j = findMax(range, enterArray);
            swap(j, range, enterArray);
            range = range -1;
         }
         return enterArray;
      }
      }
```

Now the code is printing an array that looks like this: [D@15db9742
What's wrong now?

Comment: What error does it return?

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error message is:

```
Driver01.java:41: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion
                         from double to int
            swap(j, range, enterArray);
                 ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose
      to get full output
1 error
```

From this, it is clear that you are calling `swap` with a `double` argument when it is expecting an `int` argument.

Now I am not going to suggest a solution, but I would advise you to carefully look at what `findMax` is doing and what it is returning.  Particularly the return **type**!

(Part of the problem here is that the name of the `findMax` variable is misleading.  The method doesn't do what the name implies that it does.)

Comment: So I've edited the code and it compiles. However it is returning a weird array, I've revised the original question to include the revised code. What is wrong now?

Comment: See comment above.